# Button / ToggleButton / EditText layouts messed up in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a togglebutton inside a relativelayout setup like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/myBack"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="906dp"
   android:background="@drawable/main" >

<ToggleButton
     android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
     android:background="@drawable/send_toggleLayout"
     android:checked="true"
     android:text="ToggleButton" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Anyway I could handle this so 2.3 and 4.2 have similar or atleast not as much messed up as the 2.3? I noticed this behavior is happening in the layout applied buttons, togglebuttons, and edittexts in my program. Any advice?

When this layout is applied to buttons/togglebuttons it happens. This is a sample of how the send_toggleLayout xml file looks like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:padding="10dp" android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/toggleDark"  android:endColor="@color/toggleLight" android:angle="90"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp" android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="15dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where is your turn on off title is it in the same layout?

Comment: are you using different layouts for 2.3 and 4.2 version devices or not?

Comment: @BaZinga Its in the main activity which is this RelativeLayout including the ToggleButton

Comment: @hamad I dont think so? I have the same layout file set like above

Answer (score 0):

Each generalized size and density spans a range of actual screen sizes and densities. For example, two devices that both report a screen size of normal might have actual screen sizes and aspect ratios that are slightly different when measured by hand. Similarly, two devices that report a screen density of hdpi might have real pixel densities that are slightly different. Android makes these differences abstract to applications, so you can provide UI designed for the generalized sizes and densities and let the system handle any final adjustments as necessary.

visit this for more info: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

and you can use diffenet shape files for different Layouts:
and create shape file with 2 or 3 radius

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:padding="10dp" android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/toggleDark"  android:endColor="@color/toggleLight" android:angle="90"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

i have changed the radius of corners so that it look perfect on 2.3
android device know which layout should be loaded on according to density.
so create different shape files for different layouts.
use different emulators to view the out put.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

or use this to know which device your are using:
Execute the following code:

```
float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

and check the value of scale:

```
0.75 means low density
1.0 means standard (medium) density
1.5 means high (large) density
2.0 means extra high density
```

Comment: I read through this page. I followed the guidelines, used DP and everything. I am not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @RaGhazi i have updated my answer, it will solve your problem

Comment: thank you.. but I want the corners to be 15dp for Android 4.2 and above. Is there a way I can check if the user's device is 4.2+ and change the xml file?

Comment: @RaGhazi update answer,it will solve your problem,so mark this as answer to help others also

Comment: ok Thanks I will.. But the next question I have is... what if I do it and (this is extremely rare) but what if there is a device that runs android 4.2 but is small? Which layout would it pick to run?

Comment: in the world of android,the all device have these four densities,so don't worry about that.android will choose suitable layout automatically to load.so don't worry about that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37297/discussion-between-hamad-and-ra-ghazi)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/myBack"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/txt"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Turn on/off alerts"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    />
<ToggleButton
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:checked="true"
     android:text="ToggleButton" 
     />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post the entire code. (not technically allowed for school work). The textview is also inside the relativelayout with the togglebutton

Comment: yeah I already have the textview inside the relativeLayout and its giving me that messed up layout

Comment: have you try this xml snippet?

Comment: Yes. That is what I have right now but in the Togglebutton I set the background. I want to set a design for a ToggleButton.

Comment: yes you can add your properties in it also. add what you missing in this xml snippet like android:background="@drawable/send_toggleLayout"

Comment: I did. Still nothing same layout in 2.3